# how to retrieve the inside of my tag on click

Tags: reactjs

How to retrieve the inside of my  tag on click

I have tried something like this at the creation of the element but the value of `i` is always equal to the last value in `onClick`.

```
heads = ['alligator', 'snake', 'lizard'];
for (var i = 0; i < size;i++){
    tHead.push(<th onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(heads[i])}> {heads[i]} </th>);
}
```

Comment: please provide heads array

Comment: just something like var heads = ['alligator', 'snake', 'lizard'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
heads.forEach((head)=>{
    tHead.push(<th onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(head)> {head} </th>});
}
```

The advantage of using forEach over a for loop is that the index and value are bound to a specific loop iteration instead of the surrounding scope. Thus when the loop index changes the closures keep the old loop-index.

This will also work:

```
heads.forEach((_, index)=>{
    tHead.push(<th onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(heads[index])> {heads[index]} </th>});
}
```

or this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < size;i++){
    let j = i;
    tHead.push(<th onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(heads[j])}> {heads[j]} </th>);
}
```

The last one works because `j` is bound to a specific loop iteration, so it will not change while `i` will.